# Facebook Ads Insights API Could not fetch Budget

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I am working on facebook ads api v2.5 to get the ad account stats.Below is the code I am using it to get the data :-

```
$params = array(
                'date_preset' => InsightsPresets::LAST_30_DAYS,
                'level' => InsightsLevels::CAMPAIGN,
                'limit' => 1000,
            );
            $fields = array(
                InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_NAME,
                InsightsFields::CAMPAIGN_ID,
                InsightsFields::DATE_START,
                InsightsFields::DATE_STOP,
                InsightsFields::IMPRESSIONS,
                InsightsFields::SOCIAL_IMPRESSIONS,
                InsightsFields::UNIQUE_CLICKS,
                InsightsFields::REACH,
                InsightsFields::SPEND,
                InsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTIONS,
                InsightsFields::TOTAL_ACTION_VALUE,
                InsightsFields::ACTIONS
            );


            $insights = $account->getInsights($fields, $params);
```

I also need to fetch the campaign budget, but can't seems to find any way to get campaign budget.

Any idea how can I get Campaign budget??

Thanks,
Ronak Shah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Budget is defined on adset level (see [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign)) and it's rather a static value than a statistical one. Therefore you have to use classic reading request on adset by its ID.

Campaign names and IDs are available in insights, so that you can pair the insights with advert objects.

Relevant adset fields are `LIFETIME_BUDGET`, `DAILY_BUDGET` and `BUDGET_REMAINING`.

There is also campaign field named `SPEND_CAP`, but I'm not sure that's something everyone can use. And really the budget is typically set on adset level.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.BTW though I had already got answer from PHP sdk but still +1 vote for you, Thanks again